# How to create a .txt with users IP using Javascript + PHP for a "Accept new Policy"?

Tags: javascript, php, json

im trying to do a .txt with user IPs using this API: https://ipinfo.io/?format=jsonp&callback=getIP , after receive a JSON object im trying to save this on a .txt file using PHP. The .txt file needs to be add with every user IP that enter the website. Is that possible ?

The idea of this is to be a recorder of users for a button of "Accept new Policy" on a website running php.

I have this on my index.html:

```
<script type="application/javascript">


const newJson = {}
const jsonString = JSON.stringify($newJson);
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();


xhr.open("POST", "cookie.php");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
xhr.send(jsonString);

  function getIP(json) {
    
    newJson= json;
    
    
    
  }
</script>
<script type="application/javascript" src="https://ipinfo.io/?format=jsonp&callback=getIP"></script>
```

And this on my cookie.php:

```
<?php

$requestPayload = file_get_contents("php://input");

var_dump($requestPayload);

?>
```

Thanks for the help. (:

Comment: the file in the server or in the visitor side ??

Comment: @AlaaKaddour hello, only on server side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the html make it like this :

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport"
        content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js" integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script type="application/javascript">
$.getJSON('https://api.ipify.org?format=json', function(data){
    console.log(data.ip);
     $.ajax({
            type : "POST",  //type of method
            url  : "cookie.php",  //your script php
            data : { ip:data.ip },// passing the values
            success: function(res){  
                                    //do what you want here...
                    }
        });
});
</script>


</head>
<body>


</body>
</html>
```

MAKE SURE YOU ARE USING JQUERY UNCOMPRESSED USE ajax LIKE THIS :

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js" integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

in the php FILE :

```
<?php

if(!empty($_POST['ip'])){
$data = $_POST['ip'];


$file = fopen("ip.txt", 'w');//creates new file
fwrite($file, $data);
fclose($file);
}
```